# Formview Mode Change - Scroll to the top of page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, scroll, formview

So once I submit a asp.net formview in insert mode, I am changing it back to 'Read Only`mode, to display user entered information. The issue I am facing is the page does not scroll to the top. I am using this javacript code, in the`OnPreRender` function for the page, but nothing is happening.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPreRender(ByVal e As EventArgs)
    'To check, if form is in ReadOnly After Recent Save Event
    If fmvExerciseRequestForm.CurrentMode = FormViewMode.ReadOnly AndAlso CurrentFormID > 0 Then
        InsertForm.Visible = False
        EditForm.Visible = True
        UserInfo.Visible = False
        ItemInfo.Visible = True
        LoadEditPage()
        Dim script As String = String.Empty
        script = "<script type=""text/javascript"" id=""ScrollScript"">window.scrollTo(0, 0);</script>"
        If (Not Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("ScrollScript")) Then
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "ScrollScript", script, False)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Please let me know, how can I scroll the page to top?

Why my script is not working?

Comment: Is the page wrapped in an update panel?

Comment: Nope, its a formview. why ?

Comment: I've seen update panels cause similar issues. Since those methods are depreciated, have you given ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered(string key) a try to see if it behaves any different? 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.isstartupscriptregistered.aspx

AND 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx